# Any way to help "visualize" the superblock, filesystem, group descriptors, etc

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, ext4

I've been reading a lot about filesystems, trying to learn all I can in depth, but I'm having trouble really visualizing some of it, especially when it comes to things like the superblock, group descriptors, etc.

I can run a dumpe2fs and see the locations of the superblock, and group descriptors, and their locations (pretty sure it is listed by sector, but not 100% sure).  But I want to take it one step further and really dig deeper.

I've tried dd'ing and cat'ing those sectors and piping them through hexdump, od, and other similar things, but not finding too much useful info.  Below is an example of the closest I can find, but it seems to be missing data where the asterisks are.

```
root@debian-vm:/# cat /dev/md8 | hexdump -C
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000400  20 51 00 00 c0 43 01 00  30 10 00 00 db 0b 01 00  | Q...C..0.......|
00000410  2c 4d 00 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |,M..............|
00000420  00 20 00 00 00 20 00 00  60 07 00 00 0e b5 64 56  |. ... ..`.....dV|
00000430  0e b5 64 56 02 00 ff ff  53 ef 01 00 01 00 00 00  |..dV....S.......|
00000440  9a 8c 64 56 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  |..dV............|
00000450  00 00 00 00 0b 00 00 00  80 00 00 00 3c 00 00 00  |............<...|
00000460  46 02 00 00 79 00 00 00  4e 9e 20 fc e4 da 4d 43  |F...y...N. ...MC|
00000470  8f 13 23 a9 b1 c4 3a fc  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..#...:.........|
00000480  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  2f 6d 6e 74 2f 74 65 73  |......../mnt/tes|
00000490  74 38 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |t8..............|
000004a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000004c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01  |................|
000004d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000004e0  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 7c 82 17 87  |............|...|
000004f0  c4 61 49 f4 88 71 e5 46  3e 33 95 04 01 01 00 00  |.aI..q.F>3......|
```

I'm really looking for a better way to truly visualize and gain a deeper understanding for the individual sectors, partitions, superblocks, filesystem metadata, etc.  The reason is simply to learn, and to be able to really break things down at a low level. Is there a better way to do this?

PS: Also I'm working with raid arrays which have an MD superblock.  But I'm having a tough time visualizing how the regular superblocks co-exist with the md superblock.  Any tips?

Comment: No data is missing. The asterisks indicate lines that are exactly as above, i.e. all zero. (See the man page of `hexdump`, especially the `-v` option.)

Answer (score 0):

A nice tool to visualize binary dumps is [BinID](http://www.phenoelit.org/fr/tools.html). (It is windows only, but should work in a VM or wine.)

When choosing a suitable line width, all "blocks" of data should be visible quite nicely.

It should also be possible to write an own tool like this, which you can adapt to your needs. - As your dump is not completely unknown and you know quite a few things about block sizes and stuff you probably should try to write a specialized tool like this.